# Chromium not opening in WSL2

Tags: chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a Linux noob using the Ubuntu 20.04 distro. I use Linux via WSL2 and my OS is Windows 10. I managed to install chromium but the app simply fails to open without a warning when I try to open it using GUI.

I tried using the terminal to open it and then this came up:

> `[0103/222716.865545:ERROR:exception_handler_server.cc(361)] getsockopt: Invalid argument`

I referred to [this video](https://youtu.be/FJ-ymbDIths) to install Chromium: . But I couldn't do one step in it, the one around 3:30 minutes as I couldn't find the *Softwares and Updates* window. I don't know whether that caused the issue. How to fix this? I haven't found any possible duplicates for this yet.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, I checked the version and found it to be version 1! I don't know why it happened though!

```
Ubuntu-20.04 | Running | 1
```

Comment: Check the following links:
1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588767/running-google-chrome-on-wsl-ubuntu-as-headless-no-sandbox-gives-multiple
2.https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/648

Comment: @Gagan Just a heads-up that the Github link is to an issue on WSL1, not WSL2.  Although that may be helpful, since it *does* sound similar (see my next response to OP).  The Stack Overflow one is specifically regarding Chrome *headless*, and I it doesn't look helpful in that case, but I could be wrong.  Is there something in that SO post that you think the OP should try?

Comment: And Hello and Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack!  That second link that @Gagan posted mentions socket issues on WSL1, which is to be expected.  But can you confirm that you are really running WSL2?   A lot of people *think* they are running it, but really are still on WSL1.  Just to double-check, run `wsl -l -v` and add the results to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, that video assumes that you are running Ubuntu Desktop, which won't run under WSL2 without some [extensive (and hacky) additional effort](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986).  You'll need to add the PPA from the command line -- [This blog](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/install-chromium-browser-ppa-ubuntu-20-04/) may have the right information, but I haven't tried it myself to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL1, people can not use a Linux version of Chrome. so just use Windows version `chrome.exe` and `chromdriver.exe`.

And my problem solved by simply `mv chromdriver.exe chromdriver`, because Selenium can only identify `chromdriver` without '.exe'.